# Pan Large Image in Scrollview through StoryBoard

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, storyboard

I am building an application where I want to display a floor plan where the image is 2952x3600, larger than the size of my view controller. I want the user to be able to pan the image and zoom in and out, similar to how a map behaves in Mapview.

I was able to obtain the desired result programmatically with the below code. However, I want to be able to add buttons to the image and it will be easier to do in the storyboard. How can I accomplish the same result in the Storyboard?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "TorontoPATHNetworkMap_v.2018.08.pdf"))
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
        scrollView.contentSize = imageView.bounds.size
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.3
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

Comment: *"... add buttons to the image ..."* In what way? Do you want buttons that scale and move as you scale and move the image? Or do you want them to "float" inside the scroll view frame (like a "+ - zoom control")? And, why do you think it would be easier to add buttons in Storyboard?

Comment: I want buttons that scale and move as I scale and move the image. I think it would be easier because I have a large number of buttons to add to an image that is larger than my view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add other UI elements (buttons, labels, subviews, etc) and have them scale and move when the scroll view content is zoomed, you have a couple options:

1) Add your buttons in code as subviews of the image view. They will move / size along with the image view.

2) If you'd find it easier to layout your buttons visually, you can do your layout in Storyboard / Interface Builder. In IB, though, you cannot add subviews to a `UIImageView`, so you will need to embed the image view and buttons in a "container" `UIView`. Then in your controller class return that `container view` from `viewForZooming`

---

**Edit**

Here's an example of setting up the views in Storyboard / IB: https://github.com/DonMag/PDFImagePanZoom

Comment: I want to layout my buttons visually. With my current code, the image doesn't show on the storyboard so I cant see where I'd like to place the buttons. When I add the same image to my image view in storyboard, it shows up underneath the image view from my code as a duplicate.

Comment: @Sal - can you post a link to your "TorontoPATHNetworkMap_v.2018.08.pdf" file? I can show you how to do what you want.

Comment: Great! Here is the link to the file- http://torontofinancialdistrict.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/TorontoPATHNetworkMap_v.2018.08.pdf

Comment: @Sal - in your question, you say *"display a floor plan where the image is `1260 x 1000`"* ... but the link you provided gives me a pdf file that loads at `2952 x 3600`?

Comment: Apologies I've updated the question. I kept a placeholder size by accident.

Comment: @Sal - See the **Edit** at the bottom of my answer. I put up an example project on GitHub.

Comment: I replicated your GitHub project and this is exactly what I was looking for. I found that panning was a bit difficult in the simulator. Also, why did you select a container view instead of a regular embedded view? I was unable to embed the image view into the container view as you have in the GitHub project

Comment: @Sal - It's a normal `UIView` - I just called it a "container" ... it's not a Storyboard `UIContainerView` object.

Comment: @Sal - not sure what you mean by *"panning was a bit difficult in the simulator"* ... works fine for me. Does it pan fine on a device? Maybe you're over-taxing your system?

Comment: I misunderstood used a UIContainer view instead of a normal UIView. My code is working exactly how I want it to. Thanks!